# HTML5 Canvas. Is it faster to render multiple smaller Images rather than one large Image that equates to the same size?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a Tilebased game at the moment. And I am wondering if it would be more expensive if I merged say 4 tiles into one larger tile and rendered that as a single image rather than rendering the 4 tiles separately each frame. I am wondering about which approach is faster in terms of performance.

Comment: Given then question title states HTML 5 would you not just use css to insert the image and apply a background-repeat to the element ?

Comment: It's HTML5 canvas, we can't exactly assume he can use the background css.

Comment: The whole game is rendered onto the canvas. Each tile looks different.

Comment: Per pixel the fewer calls to the canvas the quicker the pixel rate, but for 4 tiles instead of one the difference is marginal. For a render call and depending on the Hardware a full screen image can take the same time as a 4 by 4 pixel image, but that said on another machine with lower spec hardware the full screen image will take much longer. You need to run performance tests